# Why the implementation of inequality of matrix and vectors in such way?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, operator-keyword, equality

The implementation of the operator seems not right, but I am not sure.
Here's the link 
https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Common/nvMatrix.h 
https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Common/nvVector.h

```
        friend bool operator != (const quaternion<T> &lhs, const quaternion<T> &rhs)
        {
            bool r = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                r &= lhs._array[i] == rhs._array[i];
            }

            return r;
        }
```

so as the vector and matrix template.

```
        friend bool operator != (const vec4<T> &lhs, const vec4<T> &rhs)
        {
            bool r = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < lhs.size(); i++)
            {
                r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[i];
            }

            return r;
        }

        friend bool operator != (const matrix4 &lhs, const matrix4 &rhs)
        {
            bool r = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[i];
            }

            return r;
        }
```

Comment: The `quaternion` versions seems to be incorrect, but which part were you having trouble understanding for the `vec4` and `matrix4` version?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say, without delving into how that library represents quaternions.   But, mathematically, some operations on quaternions work in ways that are counter-intuitive to anyone without detailed specialist knowledge.   The fact that there are multiple ways the library might represent them makes it that much harder to explain how particular operations work    Of course, it may simply be a bug - bugs are more likely when developers have challenges understanding the core concepts of what they are implementing.

Comment: So someone made a typo in one instance of an operator in a CUDA sample (and note these are toy examples not intended for production use). If it bothers you, raise a bug report at the NVIDIA developer portal. Otherwise I don't really understand what the question is here

Comment: @talonmies I am a beginer for this, I am not sure if there something I had not learn about. Since the code is from the famous Nvidia.

Comment: A matrix is equal to another when all of thier elements are equal, and if there has even one different element, the 2 matrices are different. But here, all the elements must be different so the return value can be true, I can not understand this.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep  Oh!! I have not noticed that the typo in the quaternion example at first. Actually, my question is about the vec4 and matrix4 example above.

Comment: For vector and matrix once any of the conditions is false it will stay false regardless of the rest of the conditions. `1 &= 1 == 1`, `1 &= 0 == 0`, `0 &= 1 == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

> A matrix is equal to another when all of thier elements are equal, and if there has even one different element, the 2 matrices are different. But here, all the elements must be different so the return value can be true, I can not understand this.

Except that's not how the code works here. You only need one of the value to be different to return `true`.

---

Let's look at this part:

```cpp
bool r = true;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[i];
}
```

And let's assumes:

```
lhs._array = [0,1,2,3]
rhs._array = [1,1,1,3]
```

---

When `i` is `0`, `r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[i]` would become:

```
r &= 0 != 1
// or
r &= true
```

And since `true & true => true`, `r` is `true`.

---

Now, if `i` is `1`, then `r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[I]` would become:

```
r &= 1 != 1
// or
r &= false
```

And since `true & false => false`, `r` is `false` now.

---

Now, if `i` is `2`, then `r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[I]` would become:

```
r &= 2 != 1
// or 
r &= true
```

Since `false & true => false`, `r` is still `false`.

---

Now, if `i` is `3`, then `r &= lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[I]` would become:

```
r &= 3 != 3
// or 
r &= false
```

Since `false & false => false`, `r` is still `false`.

---

In conclusion,  `r` will become `false` the first time `lhs._array[i] != rhs._array[i]` is `false`, and it will stay `false` for the rest of the loop.

Comment: thanks，this answer is easy to understand.